# How to allow only specific applications to access network?

Tags: windows, security, windows-10, firewall, privacy

I'd like to let Windows 10 block all connections except those which are instantiated by specific applications. It also has to stop all connections made by Windows itself.

I could think of two options:

- Use Windows Firewall to block by default all outbound connections (but I am not sure if this will really block all own Windows processes)
- Run a virtual machine and pass the network device to it (but then there will be the same problem with the guest OS) - this will at least guarantee that any activity on the host OS will not leak...

Answer (score -1):

In windows there is not any inbuilt way to stop any application using internet. so that you have to use the third party software like net limiter. by using this you can set speed limit for every application you want.
www.netlimiter.com/